# Activity theme rendering sequence

Tags: android, themes

I want to change the theme of activity through java code, but it didn't work as what I expected.
When I set the custom_theme through Activity.onCreate() method, it seens to load mainfest_activity_theme first, and then change to custom_theme.

Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // set theme
  this.setTheme(R.style.custom_theme);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  // set content view
  this.setContentView(..);
  //..
}
```

Manifest:

```
<activity
  android:theme="@style/manifest_activity_theme">
  <!-- .. -->
</activity>
```

Render Sequence:

```
manifest_activity_theme -> custom_theme
```

I want custom_theme to be rendered directly rather than load mainfest_activity_theme for once.

Comment: why to use 2 themes if you don't want manifest_activity_theme for the activity ?

Comment: I have tried to keep the application_theme and activity_theme empty in the manifest, but it didn't work. It would render system_default_theme first, and then load the custom_theme.
I just want to load custom_theme directly.